# Are policies applied to SQL servers also apply to managed instances?

Tags: sql-server, azure, policies

1. When we specify a policy effect in Azure with following details :

```
"type": "Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/securityAlertPolicies"
```

2. Can this be also done with

```
"type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/securityAlertPolicies",
```

I think that 1 should work even with 2 as SQL managed instances are also SQL servers. Am I correct ?

Thanks in advance for your help :).

Comment: According to my research, Azure SQL Server and Azure SQL managed Instance are different Azure resources.  For more details, please refer to  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/allversions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Azure SQL and Azure SQL managed instances are different resources, we have to specify different policies for both of them.